# How to run a Gradle task when selecting a 'Run/Debug Configurations' option on AndroidStudio?

Tags: android-studio, gradle

On my android project, I have to change some files depending on which Run/Debug Configurations I've selected on Android Studio.

Is it possible to configure AndroidStudio to run a specific Gradle task immediately after selecting a Run/Debug Configurations option?

I'm aware of the "Before lunch:" option on Run/Debug Configurations screen, but it will execute the task only if running the config. I need a way to execute the task when changing the run/debug config even if not actually running it.